# How to default dry run with angular cli

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

**What:** Is there any way to default dry-run in a configuration?

**Why:** This makes learning so much easier because we don't need to cleanup as many messes if the command wasn't quite right. This could force you to first try a dry run before explicitly generating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked for a solution natively but couldn't find any answers. I ended up wrapping the `ng g` call in my `package.json`: `"ngd": "ng g -d --"`

Examples:

Provides a component, a module, etc. and accepts all parameters like normal

`npm run ngd c my/component/
 npm run ngd m moduleName
 npm run ngd d directiveName`

Comment: This is the only option I've seen so far! Thanks! I will try this out! This isn't ideal thought. We have to do extra work every time for every project and for every type of generation? So can't we do "ng g -d --" and then provide our type of generation? I'll try this out and get back. ;) Appreciate your answer!

Comment: Ok I tried this out and it seems to work how I need it to without specifying a type of generation. We can update your answer to not specify the type "c" which will allow all types of generation and accept this as the best answer for now! Thanks again!

Comment: Yes. Thanks for updating!

Comment: If you found the question valuable, let others know with an upvote. ;)